# JS custom sort a table based on text content

Tags: javascript, sorting

I've been working on this for a long time w/out success. I have a generated table which I need to re-build and re-sort by textContent.

https://codepen.io/thebigragu/pen/pojyMaO

initial table ex.

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th>Rank</th></tr>
<tr><th>ID</th></tr>
<tr><th>Pts</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>雙黑鑽石合作夥伴</td></tr>
<tr><td>黃金合作夥伴</td></tr>
<tr><td>黑鑽石合作夥伴</td></tr>
</tbody>
</html>
```

I've created an array with the correct sort order:

```
var ranks = [
  "黑鑽石合作夥伴",
  "黃金合作夥伴",
  "雙黑鑽石合作夥伴"
]
```

and I want to build a new table based on string comparison. I'm able to compare each string in the table w/ an array (w/ correct order), but when I create the new table the order doesn't change.

any feedback appreciated. ty!

Comment: Could you share your existing JS to give us an idea of how you're trying to re-draw the table currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you doing is reverse, actually you should loop over `ranks` array first and then over `tr` array because `tr` DEPEND on `ranks` (for position info.) and not the other way around

```
for(l = 0; l < ranks.length; l++){

    for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++){

        let txt = tr[i].children[0].querySelector('a').textContent;

        if( ranks.indexOf(txt) == 0 ){

          var newIndex = ranks.indexOf(txt);
          table.appendChild(tr[i]);
          ranks.shift(); // pop the top item off ranks array
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how it works

Loop over ranks --> loop over tr

In each inner loop iteration (of `tr`) check whether the `i`th `tr` item matches the text that is at FIRST POSITION of `ranks` array

If yes paste it into `<table id="resorted-table">` and **REMOVE the top item from `ranks`**   (So you can use same logic in subsequent runs of the loop)